# Insert teamcity artifact pathTeamcity into powershell script

Tags: powershell, teamcity

I am adding a project into teamcity and need to add a powershell script to change some config settings and generate a zipped artifact. I have built and tested the script file outside of teamcity but in order to make it work during the build I need to get the path where the artifact is built to.

Is there a way to replace in the code below the `c:\artifacts\myproject\build\38` with a teamcity parameter which will always pick up the latest build directory?

```
#Find and replace various app.config settings
$location = C:\Artifacts\MyProject\Build\38\myApp\myConfig.config";
(Get-Content $location) | 
ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '<add key="platform" value="xxxx"/>', '<add key="platform" value="test"/>' } |
Set-Content $location   

#Should take source directory and create a zip file from it
$source = "C:\Artifacts\MyProject\Build\38\myApp\"
$destination = "C:\Artifacts\FrontOfficeApi\Build\38\artifact.zip"

GenerateZipFile -DestinationFilePath $destination -SourcePath $source
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$buildDirectory = "%teamcity.build.chec‌​koutDir%"` Will give you the directory where the source code has been checked out to, so you can work relatively from there. This is if you are running the PowerShell as source code, otherwise you can pass parameters into a PowerShell script using the same variable.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the response. What I decided to do was to try and output the value of teamcity.build.checkoutDir to a physical file. This was for a couple of reasons. 1. for my own knowledge of how teamcity works and 2. it's a much simpler script to start with.

Comment: However when I added the PS build step and ran the build I got an error saying there was no compatible build agents. When I disabled the new step the build ran fine! The settings are: Powershell run mode: any, Bitness: x86, Script: source code, script: $buildDirectory = "%teamcity.build.chec‌​koutDir%"
$buildDirectory | Out-File c:\debug.txt. Script execution mode: Execute .ps1 from external file. Any advice would be good thanks.